# Copy column names into rows but skip it when there's no value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to send a list of column names into their rows but skip it when there's no value. What's the right way to achieve this?

```
data = {'fruit_tag': {0: 'apple', 1: 'apple', 2: 'banana', 3: 'apple', 4: 'watermelon'}, 'location': {0: 'Hong Kong', 1: 'Tokyo', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''}, 'rating': {0: 'bad', 1: 'good', 2: 'good', 3: 'bad', 4: 'good'}, 'measure_score': {0: 0.9529434442520142, 1: 0.952498733997345, 2: 0.9080725312232971, 3: 0.8847543001174927, 4: 0.8679852485656738}}
dat = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

    fruit_tag   location rating  measure_score
0       apple  Hong Kong    bad       0.952943
1       apple      Tokyo   good       0.952499
2      banana              good       0.908073
3       apple               bad       0.884754
4  watermelon              good       0.867985
```

Expected output

```
    fruit_tag             location        rating                      measure_score
0       apple  location: Hong Kong   rating: bad  measure_score: 0.9529434442520142
1       apple      location: Tokyo  rating: good   measure_score: 0.952498733997345
2      banana                       rating: good  measure_score: 0.9080725312232971
3       apple                        rating: bad  measure_score: 0.8847543001174927
4  watermelon                       rating: good  measure_score: 0.8679852485656738
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace values to strings, then empty strings to `NaN`, so if add columns names get `NaN`s with [`DataFrame.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) for add from right side, last only replace `NaN`s to empty strings:

```
dat.iloc[:, 1:] = dat.iloc[:, 1:].astype(str).replace('', np.nan).radd(dat.columns[1:] + ': ').fillna('')
print (dat)
    fruit_tag             location        rating  \
0       apple  location: Hong Kong   rating: bad   
1       apple      location: Tokyo  rating: good   
2      banana                       rating: good   
3       apple                        rating: bad   
4  watermelon                       rating: good   

                       measure_score  
0  measure_score: 0.9529434442520142  
1   measure_score: 0.952498733997345  
2  measure_score: 0.9080725312232971  
3  measure_score: 0.8847543001174927  
4  measure_score: 0.8679852485656738
```